# Angular directive: template from other file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I include a .html as my template file in an angular js instead of having the direct HTML code inside the template attribute?`

This is my code so far:

```
    .directive('navigation', ['$rootScope', '$i18next', function ($rootScope: any, $i18next: any) {
        return {
            bindToController: true,
            template: '../views/navigation-directive.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {....
```

But when running this code the only thing my browser is displaying is '../views/navigation-directive.html' in plaintext.

[image]

The current structure of my files is this.

The directive file is located in solution/script/navigation.js
the .html file is located in solution/view/navigation-directive.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change prop

```
template: '../views/navigation-directive.html',
```

to

```
templateUrl: '../views/navigation-directive.html',
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to add though that I added `<script type="text/ng-template" id="navigation.tmpl.html">` to the header of the .HTML file and instead of using the search path I used this: `templateUrl: 'navigation.tmpl.html'`.